# How to have a real atomic test in QUnit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

Say that I have two classes called `Book` and `Library` as follow:

```
var Book = function(title, author)
{
   this.title = title;
   this.author = author;
};
```

and

```
var Library = function()
{
   var dbName = 'test';

   this.getLibrary = function() {
      return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(dbName));
   };

   this.save = function(library) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(dbName, JSON.stringify(library));
   };
}

Library.prototype.addBook = function(book) {
   var library = this.getLibrary();
   library.push(book);

   this.save(library);

   return library;
};

Library.prototype.removeBook = function(book) {
   var library = this.getLibrary();

   // Find and delete the right book

   this.save(library);

   return library;
};
```

My question is: How can I Unit testing the `Library` class using QUnit to have a real atomic and independent test?

I wrote this test function but it has not satisfied me. It does not seem to be very atomic and independent since it mix several functions that I think should be tested independently. I'd like to know if there's a better way or I'm testing it good already.

```
test("test", function() {
   var library = new Library();

   deepEqual(library.getLibrary(), []);

   // Add book1
   var book1 = new Book("A book", "An author");
   deepEqual(library.addBook(book1), [book1]);
   deepEqual(library.getLibrary(), [book1]);

   // Add book2    
   book2 = new Result("A new book", "Another author");
   deepEqual(library.addBook(book2), [book2, book1]);
   deepEqual(library.getLibrary(), [book2, book1]]);

   // Remove book1
   deepEqual(library.removeResult(book1), [book2]);
   deepEqual(library.getLibrary(), [book2]);

   // Remove book2
   deepEqual(library.removeResult(book2), []);
   deepEqual(library.getLibrary(), []);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid writing "omnibus" tests that depend on internal state of the unit you're testing. Make fine-grained tests for specific *behaviours*, not state:

```
test("addBooksReturnsLibrary", function(){
    var l = new Library();
    l.addBook(new Book(...));
    l.addBook(new Book(...));
    var addBooksRetval = l.addBook(new Book(...));
    deepEqual(addBooksRetval, l.getLibrary();
});

test("libraryContainsAddedBook"), function() {
    var l = new Library();
    var b = new Book(...);
    l.addBook(b);
    notEqual(-1, library.indexOf(b));
});

// etc and so forth
```

Heavy use of `deepEqual` seems like it's a testing smell more often than not. If you do need, say, the books to be in the library in a specific order, I'd say it's better to test for those ordering constraints specifically.

Comment: Good point. But the main problem I have is that to test the removeBook, for example, I have to rely on addBook. How can I deal with this?

Comment: @user1730232 That's not a real issue though. Add/remove functionality is not orthogonal. Just test all the cases: Remove without add fails. Remove with add leaves 0 elements. Etc.

Comment: @user1730232 The operations of a single class can't be completely independent. In fact, it'd be a code smell if they were - a sign the class has too many responsibilities. If you want to be *very* formal about this I suppose you could make some sort of graph of your tests to analyse the dependencies between the behaviours, and make it doesn't consist of only cycles. But generally you can probably assume a class implementation is "sane" and not coded specifically to pass the test suite while being useless, and write tests to detect regressions etc. instead.